# how to install gcc 4.9.2 on solaris

Tags: solaris

I try to install gcc 4.9.2 on solaris 11.0 sparc

however although it says no updates neccesary it doesn't find this package:

```
-bash-4.1# pkg install gcc-49
No updates necessary for this image.
-bash-4.1# pkg list -v gcc-49
pkg list: no packages matching 'gcc-49' installed
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect the `gcc-49` package is obsolete and no longer supported.  What do you get if you add a bunch of `-v` options to the `pkg` command, like `pkg -v -v -v -v -v install gcc-49`?  FYI, the Solaris 11 package catalog is available at http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/catalog.shtml?version=entire%4011.4%2C5.11-11.4.42.0.0.111.0&action=Browse&show_all_versions=1&show_obsolete=1&show_renamed=1

Comment: bash-4.1# pkg -v -v -v -v -v install gcc-49
```pkg: illegal global option -- v
Try `pkg --help or -?' for more information.```

Comment: Per [the `pkg` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/pkg-1.html), it appears the `-v` must come after the `install` option:  `/usr/bin/pkg install [-nvq] ...`  